# Python 3 variable that contains questionmarks

Tags: sqlite, python-3.6

I'm trying to make a python3 sqlite3 database function that determines the amount of column with a for loop. During this for loop I want to add a "?" to a variable for each column.

So what I'm trying to do now is create a list from which I remove the quotes and brackets afterwards but using the .strip() and .replace() method don't seem to work for me either.

```
lijst = [] 
lijst.append("?") 
lijst.append("?") 
lijst.replace('"', '')
lijst.strip([])
print(lijst)
```

In the end I want it to look a bit like this (?, ?, ?).

Answer (score 0):

`lijst` is a `list`, not a string.  You can't treat the two interchangeably.  Instead, you can construct a string directly.  Where `n` in the number of `?` you want in your final string:

```
n = 3
result = "({})".format(", ".join("?"*n))
print(result)
# (?, ?, ?)
```